# MVC4 Web API for web development and possibly mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I really like the new feature, Web API that's released with MVC4.

I'm currently working on a web application, that I will want to extend it to a mobile application.

What would be the best way of utilizing this feature?

1. Program it like there's no Web API, and when i'm ready to develop for a mobile application, then use this feature (Copy and paste controller functions then edit the return and error handling value ?
2. Or should I use Web API from the beginning of the web development. Using javascript to call functions and to handle errros? The problem with this apporach is I'm not too familiar with JS, and the code would not look very clean (the Views)

Any opinion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the Web API shouldn't be seen as a feature specific to mobile application development. It's a tool allowing you to easily expose RESTful APIs over HTTP. Those APIs could be consumed from desktop applications, web applications, mobile applications, etc ... The interface for each type of application will of course be developed using the specific frameworks and tools for this task (WPF, ASP.NET/MVC, WP7/iOS/Android, ...).

The Web API just allows you to expose your business data and services in an interoperable way so that different clients could consume them.

Comment: That makes perfect sense and ...yeah...got it. But looking forward, how does the WebAPIController that's feeding mobile, rss, whatever - how's that controller effect the presence (or not) of a conventional MVC View controller? Should MVC Views be seen as just another of the possible formats the WebAPI is serving? thx much

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using the second approach.

In the beginning, I also thought the `.ajax` calls might mess up the Views. (No one likes to add a long `<script>` section in a View.) But after asking my questions on Stackoverflow, I am glad to find some experts here using some "code-behind" for those javascript.

The practice is:

Create a separate `JS` folder to store all the "code-behind" js files. (The default Scripts folder only contains the third-party packages like `knockout.js`, `jquery.js` and etc)

For each view, generate a `.js` file, like `home.index.js`, `form.add.js`, etc. Just follow a consistent rule. There will be a lot of `js` files created. The great thing is in MVC4, we can combine all `.js` files under this folder and generate a minified, combined, single file, and load it only once in the _Layout view.

The way to do it is:

In _Layout view, `<head>` section:

```
<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/JavaScripts/js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In `Global.asax`, `Application_Start`, register the bundle:

```
var bundle = new Bundle("~/JavaScripts/js", new JsMinify());
        bundle.AddDirectory("~/JavaScripts", "*.js", true);
        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(bundle);
        BundleTable.Bundles.EnableDefaultBundles();
        //BundleTable.Bundles.RegisterTemplateBundles();
```

Then you are good to go. The Views are still clean. All the .js files are organized. And no need to import different .js file on each individual view.

Leaning JS is not a problem. As it is probably the only client-side programming language, it is now becoming necessary for us to learn new things. And I feel it is easier since we have `jQuery` now. It is time to upgrade our knowledge. I am happy and excited about what we can accomplish with these new tools.